# How do you tell if react redux form submit attempt has occurred?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

When I look at the `$form` of my form, I see the following boolean properties:

```
focus
pending
pristine
retouched
submitFailed
submitted
touched
valid
validated
validating
```

In need to determine if an attempt was made to submit the form, whether it be successful or not.  I would expect the `submitted` property or even `submitFailed` to be used to indicate that, but not so.  If I open a form and immediately submit it, both of those properties are false.  The only time either is true is if I attempt to submit (unsuccessfully) and then correct any errors.  In that case, `submitFailed` turns true.

Something on `$form` should indicate if a submit has ever been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `submitSucceeded` in the list. This tells if the form was submitted, it will revert back to `false` after a validation error. If this does not work for your, you can add a reducer using `reducer.plugin` and reduce a submitAttempt value using the actions of the forms (or add a reducer of your own to the rootReducer).

https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/docs/api/reducerplugin.md/

Comment: Is your response with regard to the redux-form library or react-redux-form? I'm using the latter.